# How can I test a conditional component with jest in React-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a internet status bar component in react-native whose render method looks something like this:

```
render() {

if (this.state.isConnected) {
     return false
   }

   return(...)
 }
}
```

Basically if your phone cannot establish a connection, it displays a message at the top of the screen telling you to connect to the internet.

However,  the default value for `this.state.isConnected` is true and hence, when you test the snapshot in jest you simply get a null output in the snapshot ie.

```
exports[`ConnectionBar Component renders 1`] = `null`
```

I can't think of a way to mock `this.state.isConnected` to false in the test, and hence nothing gets rendered in the test snapshot.

PS: I don't want to set the default value of `this.state.isConnected` to false since I force a bit of delay before the state changes to prevent flickering and this will result in the "Check your connection" bar to show up on every screen for about a second before is disappears.

If anybody has any insight, please let me know.

Comment: are you using enzyme? if so you could do `const component = shallow(<Component />` and then `component.setState({isConnected: false})`, after which you can make your assertions.

Comment: I am not. It does seem useful, but at the moment this will be the only place I would use it so it seems a bit wasteful to add another dependency.

Comment: can you provide test snippets  you coded ?